# File Upload field not saving the data in ExperienceForms database using Save Data Submit action

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have installed the SITECORE FORMS EXTENSIONS(9.0). Now, when I'm using the *File upload* field and trying to save the data in the ExperienceForms database using the *Save Data* Submit action, it does not save. How can I save the data of the file upload field in the database?

Also, while debugging I find out that the file and value both are coming null.
Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Any Solution??

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a FileStorageProvider in your configuration.

http://onelittlespark.bartverdonck.be/sitecoreformsextentions/1.8.3/developerdoc/install.html#file-upload

With the module, a provider for local disk and for Azure blob storage is available. You can also plugin your own custom storageprovider.

In the database, a reference to these files is stored. Be cautious with the local disk provider on a loadbalanced CD, the storage location should be the same for all instances of your loadbalanced environment.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Did you know why the file and value both are coming null as shown - https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkzNy.png